# How to use a calculated value as if it's a column value in Laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project that has a project model which looks like this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'category_id', 'units', 'b_price', 's_price', 'warn_count', 'added_by'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function stock(){
        $product_id = $this->id;
        $filter = ['product_id' => $product_id];
        //STOCK PLUS
        //credit purchases
        $cr_purchases = CreditPurchase::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //purchases
        $purchases = Purchase::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //returns in
        $re_in = ReturnIn::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //STOCK MINUS
        //credit sales
        $cr_sales = CreditSale::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //sales
        $sales = Sale::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //returns out
        $re_out = ReturnOut::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //damaged
        $damaged = DamagedProduct::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        return $cr_purchases + $purchases + $re_in - ($cr_sales + $sales + $re_out + $damaged);
    }
}
```

As can be seen stock is a calculated value for each model. I wish to make queries based on it as though it were a column of the products table.

Comment: What database are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL ...) and how would you like to query it?

Comment: Am using MySQL database.

Comment: I want to do something like this: `Product::where($category_filter)
            ->where($product_filter)
            ->whereBetween('stock', [$lQty, $uQty])
            ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
     ->paginate(11);`

Comment: stock should behave like a column of the model

Comment: Looks like you might do well with abstracting some methods, and then you can also have a method which checks the stock, you don't need to use query builder for everything in one shot. You can get some, check the stock, have it return a collection and then still be able to order and pagination

Comment: I don't mind about the bottle-neck introduced by the callback. The app l am working on is not very demanding.

Comment: If l can get a solution that would accommodate it on an eloquent query then l would gladly take it.

Comment: @mwiti Probably using `where($product_filter)` and `whereBetween('stock', [$lQty, $uQty])` together doesn't have whole lot of sense. `stock()` returns  a singular value per product. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I kind of had a complicated reason for using where twice. The filtering options on the interface are rather complicated. I only found it useful to separate them. You can just assume that `where($product_filter)` does not exist on the query. I just need a way of having `whereBetween('stock', [$lQty, $uQty])'

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**
Change the stock method to be an Laravel model accessor.

```
public function getStockAttribute(){
   //code logic
}
```

Fetch the results as  a Collection and  perform filters on the 'stock; attribute

I would do something like.

```
Products::where('product','like','miraa') //where
->get()
->filter(function($item) {
    return $item->stock > 100;
});
```

Read about filtering [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-filter)

**Method 2**

Use dynamic query scopes
See [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes) in laravel.

```
public function scopeAvailbaleStock($query, $type)
{
    return $query->where('type', $type);
    // could perform filters here for the query above
}
```

Fetch using scope

```
$users = Products::available_stock()->get();
```

**Method 3**
I saw out this package [jarektkaczyk/eloquence](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence)

```
public function scopeWhereStock($query, $price, $operator = '=', $bool = 'and'){
    $query->where('info1', $operator, $price, $bool);
   }

// then
Products::whereStock(25); // where('info1', 25);
Products::whereStcok(25, '>'); // where('info1', '>', 25);
Products::whereStock(25, '=', 'or'); // orWhere('info1', 25);
```

Howerever, i would recomend to use method 1 or 2. The 3rd solution works but not sure if it is the best

Comment: l now have stock on the models but the problem is l can't use stock as a query parameter like `where('stock', '>', 90);`. This would allow me to call paginate on the query like `where('stock', '>', 90)->paginate(11);`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by overriding $appends on the model and using an accessor for the stock field. So that the model now looks like:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'category_id', 'units', 'b_price', 's_price', 'warn_count', 'added_by'];
    protected $appends = ['stock'];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function getStockAttribute(){
        $product_id = $this->id;
        $filter = ['product_id' => $product_id];
        //STOCK PLUS
        //credit purchases
        $cr_purchases = CreditPurchase::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //purchases
        $purchases = Purchase::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //returns in
        $re_in = ReturnIn::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //STOCK MINUS
        //credit sales
        $cr_sales = CreditSale::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //sales
        $sales = Sale::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //returns out
        $re_out = ReturnOut::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        //damaged
        $damaged = DamagedProduct::where($filter)->sum('qty');
        return $cr_purchases + $purchases + $re_in - ($cr_sales + $sales + $re_out + $damaged);
    }
}
```

I built this solution on @samueldervis answer. A simple example can be seen here: http://laraveldaily.com/why-use-appends-with-accessors-in-eloquent/